# What was the elo distribution of Leauge of Legends at the start of season 4?

Tags: league-of-legends

As of today, tons of league statistic sites exist and there already have been some statistics about the player distribution throughout all tiers and divisions but I'm looking for a statistic which is up to date right now or even better: always accurate.

Since Season 4 now has officially started and I assume that all the players that enjoy ladder climbing have started playing their ranked matches, I think the statistics would be accurate enough.

[This](http://mmrtrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/tier-distribution.png) would be an example from a mid season 3 statistic by the way.

Comment: I'd suggest swapping the question to tier distribution if thats what you're looking for. Elo is a relic of season 2 hah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a website with statistics that look promising. [Op.gg](http://euw.op.gg/statistics/tier/) seems to track all the players of every region.